# Passing environment variable to PHP on the command-line

Tags: environment-variables, php

On CentOS, I'm trying to pass an environment variable to a PHP script.

I've created this file, `test.php`:

```php
<?php print_r($_ENV);
```

When I run this command:

```
DB=mysql php test.php
```

I get the following output:

```
Array
(
)
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Something in PHP, because even without your extra `DB` environment variable, there should be plenty of them.

Comment: @derobert Did you vote to move this to Stackoverflow? I specifically chose to ask it here because I thought it would be closed on Stackoverflow as off-topic, because it's about environment variables on Linux!

Comment: Yes. Most likely, you need to fix your setting of `variables_order` and/or use `getenv()`. Accessing the Unix environment variables (from a particular programming language, i.e., PHP) should be on-topic on SO... Though I wouldn't be surprised if there is a duplicate there.

Comment: @derobert Thank you, I just checked `variables_order` and noticed that it does not populate `$_ENV` by default, I did not know that! I thought this config was only about populating the `$_REQUEST` variable (and global variables in previous versions of PHP).

Comment: Indeed, I would have noticed the dup if only I knew that `$_ENV` should not be empty by default! Thanks for your help anyway, much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check your [`variables_order` `php.ini` variable](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order). It has to contain `E` for `$_ENV` to be populated. You can also do:

```
$ DB=whatever php -d variables_order=E -r 'echo $_ENV["DB"];'
whatever
```

Alternatively, you can use [`getenv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) which will work regardless of the value of `variables_order`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [getenv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) function:

```
$ cat test.php
<?php
    print_r(getenv('DB'));
?>

$ DB=msql php test.php
mysql
```